# Sorting csv column by dollar amount then removing duplicates

Tags: python, csv, sorting, duplicates

I have a csv file that looks like:

[image: ![excel spreadsheet]

I have read almost all of the other topics on this but can't figure it out.
I need to read in the file, sort the income column from highest to lowest and then remove any counties that have duplicates since the same county can be in a different state.

```
import csv
import operator

reader = csv.reader(open("data.csv"))
sorted_list = sorted(reader, key=(operator.itemgetter(10)), reverse=True)


with open("high_county_spend.csv", "w") as f:
  csv.writer(f).writerows(sorted_list)
```

I have tried this:

```
sorted_list = sorted(reader, key=int(operator.itemgetter(10).split("$")), reverse=True)
```

But `operator.itemgetter` doesn't have a `split(`) attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

```
import pandas as pd

# read data
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
# convert the string column to an int
df['income'] = df['income'].str.strip('$').astype(int) # or float if there are decimals .astype(float)
# sort values and drop duplicates
new_df = df.sort_values('income', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by *It_is_Chris*, the pandas library is propably advisable, but to answer your question:

```
import operator
reader = ['$10', '$20', '$5']

sorted(reader, key=lambda x: int(x.split("$")[-1]), reverse=True)


Out[204]: ['$20', '$10', '$5']
```

The problem is that `operator.itemgetter(n)` expects an iterable object (e.g. list) but you provided an integer.